# Why I am not able to upload screenshot image while asking question through SE Android App?

Tags: bug, android-app, uploader

When I tried to upload my screenshot image, I got a error message saying "Sorry, we are not able to upload that image'. I tried image from device.

What would be reason for this error message?

Is it problem with the App or with the image format? I hope the default screenshot image format would be JPEG that should be supported by SE app.

Device: I'm using my new Redmi 4 handset with Android 6.0.1 OS installed.

Comment: Probably too big, imgur can accept only up to 2MB image from SE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably Screenshots will be in ~KBs

Comment: @SagarV good point. Sathiya can you check the screenshot details and tell us here?

Comment: It works for me ... Though it is taking a lot more time than it used to after the recent updates...

Comment: @ShadowWizard its 186kb, PNG format, 720×1280 px. Is any thing more needed??

Comment: @ADITYA im using the updated app and it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. Please add to the question what device you have, so if anyone from the team will ever take a look (which I highly doubt) they can at least have a starting point to reproduce.

Comment: @ShadowWizard sure. Thanks for ur replies. Will add the device details in my question now.